# c++ write vectors to hdf5-file without storing in array

Tags: c++, vector, hdf5

I'm trying to store 4 vectors (of variable size, but all 4 have the same size) in an .h5 file.
Until now, I did it like this:

```
void write_file_h5(std::string filename,
            std::vector<int16_t> &x,
            std::vector<int16_t> &y,
            std::vector<int8_t> &p,
            std::vector<int32_t> &ts)
{
  struct myEvent myEvents[x.size()];
  for (int i=0; i<x.size();i++)
  {
    myEvents[i].x = x[i];
    myEvents[i].y = y[i];
    myEvents[i].p = int(p[i]);
    myEvents[i].ts = ts[i];
  }
  H5::CompType mtype(sizeof(myEvent));
  // Define the datatype to pass HDF5
  mtype.insertMember("x", HOFFSET(myEvent, x), H5::PredType::NATIVE_INT16);
  mtype.insertMember("y", HOFFSET(myEvent, y), H5::PredType::NATIVE_INT16);
  mtype.insertMember("p", HOFFSET(myEvent, p), H5::PredType::NATIVE_INT8);
  mtype.insertMember("ts", HOFFSET(myEvent, ts), H5::PredType::NATIVE_INT32);


  // preparation of a dataset and a file.
  hsize_t dim[1];
  dim[0] = sizeof(myEvents) / sizeof(myEvent);
  int rank = sizeof(dim) / sizeof(hsize_t);
  H5::DataSpace space(rank, dim);
  H5::H5File *file = new H5::H5File(filename, H5F_ACC_TRUNC);
  H5::DataSet *dataset = new H5::DataSet(file->createDataSet("myDataset", mtype, space));
  dataset->write(myEvents, mtype);
  delete dataset;
  delete file;
}
```

The problem with this is: As the vectors get bigger (vector size > 732428), I get a segmentation fault:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I assume that's because the the array I'm trying to create would just be too big.
Does anyone have an idea on how to solve that issue? i.e. how to write the vectors while using a minimum amount of memory?
I need the vectors because I need to fill them dynamically during the execution of the programm... so directly storing the values in an array doesn't seem to be possible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look up iterators: for (auto xit = x.begin (); xit != x.end (); xit++) do_something_with (*xit);

Comment: You cannot obtain segmentation faults solely due to memory limitations via heap allocating (if done the right way). But in your example, you apply stack allocating which should be avoided.

Comment: `struct myEvent myEvents[x.size()];` - This is a VLA (non-standard). Use `std::vector<myEvent> myEvents(x.size());` instead. Have you also checked that all the incoming vectors have the same size?

Comment: Do you _have_ to use `new` and `delete` for the `H5` classes? Instead of `H5::H5File *file = new H5::H5File(filename, H5F_ACC_TRUNC);` (and then `delete file`) it'd be cleaner with `H5::H5File file(filename, H5F_ACC_TRUNC);` and no `delete`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks for your answers. The segmentation fault indeed happens at the "struct MyEvent myEvents[x.size()];" line... so this has to be a problem. However, it must be a struct and not a vector, since vectors are not accepted by the H5 class. Also, i checked that all the incoming vectors have the same size... Do you have an idea on how to fix the struct thing?

Comment: "_it must be a struct and not a vector_" - It's an array right now. A variable length array (which is likely placed on the stack). Just replace it with what I wrote and instead of `dim[0] = sizeof(myEvents) / sizeof(myEvent);` you write `dim[0] = myEvents.size();` and instead of `dataset->write(myEvents, mtype);` you write `dataset->write(myEvents.data(), mtype);` - I'll write an answer with my suggested changes instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
struct myEvent myEvents[x.size()];
```

creates a [variable-length array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array) which is a non-standard (in C++) array that is likely placed on the stack.

Replace that with a `std::vector<myEvent>` to allocate the memory on the heap instead.

```
void write_file_h5(std::string filename,
            std::vector<int16_t> &x,
            std::vector<int16_t> &y,
            std::vector<int8_t> &p,
            std::vector<int32_t> &ts)
{
  // Suggestion: check that y, p and ts has at least as many elements as x
  std::vector<myEvent> myEvents(x.size());  // replacement for the VLA

  for (int i=0; i<x.size();i++) {
    myEvents[i].x = x[i];
    myEvents[i].y = y[i];
    myEvents[i].p = int(p[i]);
    myEvents[i].ts = ts[i];
  }

  H5::CompType mtype(sizeof(myEvent));
  // Define the datatype to pass HDF5
  mtype.insertMember("x", HOFFSET(myEvent, x), H5::PredType::NATIVE_INT16);
  mtype.insertMember("y", HOFFSET(myEvent, y), H5::PredType::NATIVE_INT16);
  mtype.insertMember("p", HOFFSET(myEvent, p), H5::PredType::NATIVE_INT8);
  mtype.insertMember("ts", HOFFSET(myEvent, ts), H5::PredType::NATIVE_INT32);

  // preparation of a dataset and a file.
  hsize_t dim[1];
  dim[0] = myEvents.size();                   // using vector::size()
  int rank = sizeof(dim) / sizeof(hsize_t);
  H5::DataSpace space(rank, dim);

  H5::H5File *file = new H5::H5File(filename, H5F_ACC_TRUNC);
  H5::DataSet *dataset = new H5::DataSet(file->createDataSet("myDataset", mtype, space));
  dataset->write(myEvents.data(), mtype);     // use vector::data()
  delete dataset;
  delete file;
}
```

I also suggest *not* using `new` and `delete` to simplify the last part of the function with:

```
  H5::H5File file(filename, H5F_ACC_TRUNC);
  H5::DataSet dataset(file.createDataSet("myDataset", mtype, space));
  dataset.write(myEvents.data(), mtype);
```